# How to hide the NavigationDrawer after item from its ListVIew is clicked?

Tags: android

Simple example of what i want to do - when you open Google Play app and click on the top left corner - a `Navigation Drawer` appears. Then if you click on any option, say "**My apps**" for exapmle, the `Navigation Drawer` hides and a new window (probably a `Fragmen`) appears. So how to hide it when an item is being clicked?

What i did so far:

1. Added `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>` as a root element
   of my `Activity`'s layout. In this element i have two children - a
   `ViewPager` for the main content, separated in few `Fragments` and a
   `ListView` to load the available options.
2. Created `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and then set it to the
   `DrawerLayout` using `setDrawerListener(myDrawerToggle);`

Any suggestions will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On ListItem click

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
```

Where `drawerLayout` is the drawer and `drawerList` is the listview.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#closeDrawer(android.view.View)

> public void closeDrawer (View drawerView)
>
> Close the specified drawer view by animating it into view.
>
> Parameters drawerView Drawer view to close

You can download the sample app from

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: I suspected that it will be something simple and it really is... Piece of cake, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you create the Drawer layout in your mainactivity and you have the Variable name for List so you just use this line in your Activity......
You just declare this variable in global and just use in the activity anyware....

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

All the best